# how to separate values with comma as delimiter

Tags: shell-script

i have a code that separates values which is delimited by ","
but having issue with the part with "to_date". Any idea on how i can achieved such.

INPUT

```
8363892,14932126,24,'ALL','Staff',to_date('04/17/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY) HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('05/24/2017 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

OUTPUT

```
8363892  
14932126  
24  
'ALL'  
'Staff'  
to_date('04/17/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY) HH24:MI:SS')  
to_date('05/24/2017 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only "false" postive you are having is the one between hour and MM/DD/YYYY string, you can convert that comma to another character before changing the rest of the commas by a carriage return, I mean:

```
echo "8363892,14932126,24,'ALL','Staff',to_date('04/17/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY) HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('05/24/2017 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'" | sed -e "s/','MM/';'MM/g" | tr ',' '\n'
```

If you want to revert changes after it:

```
echo "8363892,14932126,24,'ALL','Staff',to_date('04/17/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY) HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('05/24/2017 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'" |
sed -e "s/','MM/';'MM/g" |
tr ',' '\n' | 
sed -e "s/';'MM/','MM/g"
```